# Generic word for peformer, speaker, teacher for events

Tags: synonyms

I run an event website and have always struggled with finding the right word for the performers of an event. These events might be:

- A concert (performer)
- A workshop (teacher)
- A book reading (author)
- A speech (speaker)

Basically I am looking for the best word that might encompass all. I use "people" now but its a bit lame imo.  I need the complimentary word for "attendee" like payer is to payee.

Comment: The opposite of *attendee* is *absentee.* Use that.

Comment: I guess I dont mean opposite in that sense - I mean the complimentary word like payer/payee

Comment: *Presenter*, though that's a little iffy with artistic performers.

Comment: You could refer to all performers, teachers, authors, and speakers as *featured guests.*

Comment: It's probably too informal, but: the "talent"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, *featured* or *special guest*

---

> [**Featured Guest**](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/featured-guest.1022754/): a person, such as an entertainer [or other eminence], who has been invited to appear on a television, radio programme, in a performance or for a show and whose name appears as such on promotional leaflets (i.e., his/her name has been featured):
>
> • Our *special guest* on the programme tonight is Robert de Niro.
>
> • Madonna made a *guest appearance* at the concert.
>
> • Simon Rattle will be the *guest conductor* with the London Symphony Orchestra.

---

(Teafrog’s answer from *WordReference.com*)

---

> [**featured**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/featured) *adjective*: **2**. displayed, advertised, or presented as a *special* attraction.
>
> [**feature**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feature) *noun*: 4. a special attraction: as: **b**. a featured article, story, or department in a newspaper or magazine [or, *guest*, *star*, *eminence*].

---

> [**guest**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guest) *noun*: **4**. a usually prominent person not a regular member of a cast or organization who appears in a program or performance.

---

> [**eminence**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eminence) noun: 1) a condition of being well-known and successful, 2) a person of high rank or achievements.

---

(all linked definitions courtesy of WordReference.com & Merriam-Webster *online*)